# When will interest rates on savings accounts increase (UK)

Tags: interest-rate, interest, savings-account

Note: question related to UK savings accounts

4 days ago the Bank of England increased the bank rate from 2.25% to 3% which I understand will increase interest rates on mortgages and savings accounts for the majority of UK banks.

My question is, approximately how long will it take for banks to react and offer higher rates of interest on savings accounts?

Comment: Regularly monitor the rate at your favorite “high rate” bank.  That’s the only real way to know.  Heck, they might have already raised their rate…

Comment: This question is *not* opinion-based.